# IE - prevent errors from being shown in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling

I am developing a web application.  My application works great on chrome and firefox, but from some reason is rises some errors in IE. Even though several errors arise, the application can still run smoothly, with no apparent problem.

I'd like to hide the errors from the end user, as currently he is presented with a small icon that says an error occurred.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: (joking): try / catch everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do, by far, is figure out where the code is causing the error and fix that.

**Update:** The below is true for IE8, but not IE9 or IE11 (and so probably not true for IE10):

Because this is specifically happening in IE, you *could* use [`window.onerror`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to handle (suppress) them if they're runtime (not compilation) errors, which from your comment on another answer it sounds like they are. From that link:

> To suppress the default Internet Explorer error message for the `window` event, set the `returnValue` property of the `event` object to `true` or simply return `true` in Microsoft JScript.
>
> The `onerror` event fires for run-time errors, but not for compilation errors. In addition, error dialog boxes raised by script debuggers are not suppressed by returning `true`. To turn off script debuggers, disable script debugging in Internet Explorer by choosing **Internet Options** from the **Tools** menu. Click the **Advanced** tab and select the appropriate check box(es).

**Example:**

This code causes an error (because I'm trying to dereference `undefined`):

```
document.getElementById('theButton').onclick = function() {
  var d;

  display(d.foo);
};
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/aneji3/1)

But if we add this, the error is suppressed because we tell IE we handled it:

```
window.onerror = function() {
  // Return true to tell IE we handled it
  return true;
};
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/aneji3/2)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in IE 11. returning `true` from the onerror handler still logs an error to the console.

Comment: @Hans - I can verify that. Also verified it doesn't work in IE9, just IE8. Interesting. I guess when they switched to making script errors effectively silent unless you opened devtools, they stopped making them suppressable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no real way to do this because you would then be controlling the browser (AKA the application) and this would be a bad thing. The user can [manually turn off those errors](http://help.msn.com/resources/targeted/en-US/msnsearchtoolbar_v1/content/SEARCHTBAR_PROC_ScriptErr.htm), or you can see if you can fix your JavaScript. But, other than those two solutions, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @vondip: Recommend asking a separate question as a separate question.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken. It would be better to document the steps

Answer (score 2):

Fix the errors - most of the time, they would be something trivial that only IE trips on. For those cases, fixing the problems found by JSLint helps with 90% of the stuff: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html